# Rotated Dragshadow (Xamarin, Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, rotation, dropshadow

I have an rotated textview and I want to drag and drop this view.
The problem is that the drag shadow has no rotation.

I found a solution for android in java but this does not work for me. 
Maybe I translate the code wrong

[How to drag a rotated DragShadow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049938/how-to-drag-a-rotated-dragshadow)

```
class CustomDragShdowBuilder : View.DragShadowBuilder
{
    private View _view;
    public CustomDragShdowBuilder(View view)
    {
        _view = view;
    }

    public override void OnDrawShadow(Canvas canvas)
    {
        double rotationRad = Math.ToRadians(_view.Rotation);
        int w = (int)(_view.Width * _view.ScaleX);
        int h = (int)(_view.Height * _view.ScaleY);
        double s = Math.Abs(Math.Sin(rotationRad));
        double c = Math.Abs(Math.Cos(rotationRad));

        int width = (int)(w * c + h * s);
        int height = (int)(w * s + h * c);

        canvas.Scale(_view.ScaleX, _view.ScaleY, width / 2, height / 2);
        canvas.Rotate(_view.Rotation, width / 2, height / 2);
        canvas.Translate((width - _view.Width) / 2, (height - _view.Height) / 2);

        base.OnDrawShadow(canvas);
    }

    public override void OnProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point shadowTouchPoint)
    {
        shadowTouchPoint.Set(shadowSize.X / 2, shadowSize.Y / 2);
        base.OnProvideShadowMetrics(shadowSize, shadowTouchPoint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found a solution for android in java but this does not work for me. Maybe I translate the code wrong

Yes, you are translating it wrong, you did change the codes of `OnDrawShadow` but you didn't pay attention to `OnProvideShadowMetrics`, which aims at changing the size of the canvas drawing area, so you need to pass the same width and height that has been calculated by codes:

Here is the modified version of `DragShdowBuilder`:

```
public class MyDragShadowBuilder : DragShadowBuilder
{
    private int width, height;

    // Defines the constructor for myDragShadowBuilder
    public MyDragShadowBuilder(View v) : base(v)
    {
    }

    // Defines a callback that sends the drag shadow dimensions and touch point back to the system.
    public override void OnProvideShadowMetrics(Android.Graphics.Point outShadowSize, Android.Graphics.Point outShadowTouchPoint)
    {
        double rotationRad = Java.Lang.Math.ToRadians(View.Rotation);
        int w = (int)(View.Width * View.ScaleX);
        int h = (int)(View.Height * View.ScaleY);
        double s = Java.Lang.Math.Abs(Java.Lang.Math.Sin(rotationRad));
        double c = Java.Lang.Math.Abs(Java.Lang.Math.Cos(rotationRad));


        //calculate the size of the canvas 
        //width = view's width*cos(rad)+height*sin(rad)
        width = (int)(w * c + h * s);
        //height = view's width*sin(rad)+height*cos(rad)
        height = (int)(w * s + h * c);

        outShadowSize.Set(width, height);

        // Sets the touch point's position to be in the middle of the drag shadow
        outShadowTouchPoint.Set(outShadowSize.X / 2, outShadowSize.Y / 2);
    }

    // Defines a callback that draws the drag shadow in a Canvas that the system constructs
    // from the dimensions passed in onProvideShadowMetrics().
    public override void OnDrawShadow(Canvas canvas)
    {

        canvas.Scale(View.ScaleX, View.ScaleY, width/2 , height/2);
        //canvas.DrawColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
        canvas.Rotate(View.Rotation,width/2, height / 2);
        canvas.Translate((width - View.Width)/2, (height - View.Height) / 2);
        base.OnDrawShadow(canvas);
    }

}
```

And here is the complete sample:[RotatedTextViewSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/RotatedTextViewSample)

Comment: Thank you, Thank you and Thank you! Just what i wanted